# Get URL currently read by the player

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using Exoplayer to read some HLS streams.

I want to retrieve the URL read by the player. I read the doc, but did not find a such method / property...

Thanks.

Comment: Since you provided the URL to the player, you know what the URL is -- right?

Comment: Except for redirections : I give a **URL A** to the player. By reading this URL, the player will follow a redirection and will play a **URL B**. Here is the problem : The URL read by the player is different from the one given at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I used

```
player.currentMediaItem?.playbackProperties?.uri
```

to find out what source the player is currently using.

Answer (score 2):

Since `playbackProperties` is deprecated, use the following for recent versions of ExoPlayer:

```
MediaItem mediaItem = mPlayer.getCurrentMediaItem();
if (mediaItem != null) {
  manifestUrl = mediaItem.localConfiguration.uri.toString();
} else {
  Log.w(TAG, "No media item loaded in player!");
}
```